# Undeclared Method Error Objective C IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods

i am new to Obejctive C, so please forgive me if this is a simple question.  i am trying to get the below code to work (from the Facebook IOS integration tutorial),but i get an error at the line

```
- (void) logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [facebook logout];
```

I get the error

"use of undeclared identifier" logoutButtonClicked. I know that this is saying i am implementing a method that is not defined.  So my question is, where is the method being defined in the code below?

i have seen a solution here posted but it does not work for me, this error persists.
I have tried alternatives to try and fix, but could some one please confirm what this block of code is doing.

My understanding is that, we start of creating a pointer (logoutButton) to UIButton, and we then set the parameters of it.
We then use a selector to define an action message (LogoutButtonClicked), for the method UIControlEventTouchInside.

I don't fully understand how the method is being declared, because I thought that the line here is defining the instance method:

```
-(void) logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender {
        [facebook logout];
```

Or is the method being declared in

```
[logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonClicked)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add the logout button
    UIButton *logoutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 40);
    [logoutButton setTitle:@"Log Out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonClicked)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.viewController.view addSubview:logoutButton];
    // Method that gets called when the logout button is pressed
    - (void) logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender {
        [facebook logout];
    }
```

i would really appreciate someones help on this , have been struggling with trying to understand this to no avail.

Melvin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon is part of the selector's name:

```
@selector(logoutButtonClicked:)
                             ^
```

**NOT**

```
@selector(logoutButtonClicked)
```

Comment: This is correct but is not responsible for the error the OP asked about. The compiler doesn't care if you put an unimplemented/undefined/undeclared method's selector in `@selector()`. There's no error until runtime.

Comment: @KenThomases nope -- `-Wundeclared-selector` and `-Werror` would do it at compilation. as far as the location: good catch (+1 on your answer)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be defining a method right smack in the middle of another method.  You can't do that.  The lines:

```
- (void) logoutButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [facebook logout];
}
```

have to appear outside of any other method, not within the curly braces (`{` ... `}`) of another method.